# How to support extended curses characters with PuTTY

Tags: python, unicode, border, putty, curses

I am creating a curses program that needs to use special box characters (`│`, `─`, `┌`, etc...) that can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).  I am connecting to the Linux server where I do my programming with PuTTY.  When I just set the curses border to default (`screen.border(0)`), the border is made up of characters in the alphabet (`q`, `l`, `m`, `x`).  Is that normal?

The `curses.ACS_*` characters are also just alphabet characters on my screen.  I do not know what is wrong, but I am guessing it may have something to do with PuTTY.  I have even tried directly pasting the characters into a string, but there are lots of unicode problems with that that I cannot fix.

Any help is appreciated. -=m0dem=-

EDIT: The sample script below is what I have tried and does not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import curses
import os

os.environ["NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS"] = "1"
screen = curses.initscr()

screen.clear()
screen.refresh()
screen.border(0)
# catch
screen.getch()
curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that by default ncurses assumes that the terminal description gives the line-drawing characters (which correspond to VT100).  xterm implements this, but some developers chose to ignore the escape sequences for this when in UTF-8 mode.

Rather than make special cases for each terminal ("linux" and "screen" were enough), ncurses checks for the environment variable `NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS` (set to a nonzero value) to tell it that when in UTF-8 mode it should ignore the terminal description and just use UTF-8 constants.

This is in the ncurses FAQ *[Line-drawing characters do not appear](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#utf8_line_drawing)*, as well as in the ncurses [manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h2-ENVIRONMENT).

These features are needed to make the environment variable work as described:

- Python must be configured to use the wide-character version of ncurses ("ncursesw")
- your locale encoding must be `UTF-8`
- the environment variable `NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS` must be set to a nonzero value.

I was able to test the given script on a Debian 6 machine (a few years old), where Python is configured to use `ncursesw`, and with my locale set like this:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Because ncurses uses [`nl_langinfo(CODESET)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/nl_langinfo) when available, it tends to have a fairly reliable check for the `UTF-8` encoding.  The weak point may be some odd packages of Python (no mention was made of the platform or vintage of Python).

Python chooses the type of ncurses/ncursesw in `setup.py`; overriding that in a user script is probably not doable.  One reason why it might use ncurses rather than ncursesw is due to a conflict with the readline library which must be *compiled* to use ncurses or ncursesw. Packaging the low-level functions of ncurses/ncursesw as a common library "tinfo" can help packagers resolve this issue, but not all took advantage of this.  Here are a few links which give some insight:

- [Issue 1428494:Prefer linking against ncursesw over ncurses library](https://bugs.python.org/issue1428494)
- [Re: option to enable ncursesw in lang/python25](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.os.freebsd.devel.python/362)
- [Bug 242583: Link curses module with ncursesw.so](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=242583)
- [ports/171246: [patch] make python curses module work with unicode](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports-bugs/2012-September/239409.html)

Comment: Even if I add `os.environ["NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS"] = "1"` at the beginning, it still doesn't use box characters as the border.

Comment: If you supply a complete working script, people can test it and comment on this.

Comment: How exactly do you configure Python to use `ncursesw`?  And another thing, I do not have root access on this server.

Comment: Its Python 2.7.8 on Fedora, is there any version of Python 2 that has `ncursesw` set as the default (instead of `ncurses`)?

Comment: Your links to the Redhat bug report and Python bug report indicate that both bugs are fixed, as of 2007. And the FreeBSD ones aren't very relevant, since this is Fedora.

Comment: Fedora (and Linux in general) were not mentioned in the original question, nor to the implied question posed by the completed sample script.  I will expand the answer as needed, however.

Comment: You said you tested it out, but did you connect with PuTTY from Windows?  I think the problem is with PuTTY, since a friend tried it out using Konsole (from Linux), and the script that didn't work for me worked!

Comment: I tested with PuTTY running from OSX (this will behave no differently than from Windows, because the problem ultimately lies with PuTTY not honoring VT100 line-drawing controls when its translation is for UTF-8 - konsole and gnome-terminal would "work").

Comment: Ok, could you show me the exact code you used?  Thanks a million. :)

Comment: I used your example without change.

Answer (score 1):

I've been running my PuTTY sessions in UTF-8 because that way I don't get weirdness from Linux I8N output. A C program tool from a library (SPDK/spdk_top) running curses was outputting letters instead of border characters.

I found changing the translation on PuTTY to ISO 8859-1 gave me the nice border characters.